# Is $\mathbb R$ complete with the discrete metric?

Tags: real-analysis

How do  $\mathbb R$ is complete with the discrete metric? I know I have to show that every Cauchy sequence within $\mathbb R$ converges to a point in $\mathbb R$, but I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Do you mean $(\mathbb R, d)$ or $\mathbb R^d$? Or something else entirely? Also what do you know so far? Do you know the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: The real numbers with the discreet metric,  I.e. the distance between any a and b is 1.

Comment: Ah right. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to start building the sequence.  Can I build a ball with radius less than 1 to prove a closed set,  and since set is closed, vm

Comment: Sequence is cauchy,  therefore complete?

Comment: If the metric $d$ is discrete, for any non empty set $X$, $(X,d)$ is complete. You can look the proof  here         http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022355/prove-that-discrete-metric-space-is-complete/1022376#1022376

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $(x_n) \in \mathbb R$ be Cauchy. Then in particular, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n, m \ge N$, $$d(x_n, x_m) < \frac12$$What does this tell you about $x_n, x_m$ for $n, m \ge N$?

Note that this will be true for *any* metric space equipped with the discrete metric.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

***HINT*** What does a Cauchy sequence in a discrete space looks like? Try $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$