# Prove that discrete metric space is complete

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I understand the proof but I want to confirm one. So in discrete metric space, every Cauchy sequence is constant sequence and that way every Cauchy sequence is convergent sequence. Thus we conclude the discrete metric space is complete. Am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $x_n$ is a cauchy sequence then, for every $\epsilon>0$ exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n,m$ are greater than $N$ you have
$d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$. Now take $\epsilon=1/2$ then, it exists an $N$ such that 
$d(x_n,x_m)<1/2$ 
because d is the discrete metric, this is only possible if $x_n$ is a constant for $n$ greater than $N$

Answer (score 10):

Essentially, yes. There is merely the small technicality that a sequence can converge in a discrete metric space if it is just cofinitely constant (i.e. only finitely many terms differ from some specified value).

Comment: "Eventually constant" I would say. +1.

Comment: I think that every sequence in discrete metric space converges isn,t

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If you take $\epsilon <1$, then you will find every Cauchy sequence is a finally constant sequence.

Comment: Doesn't it have to be for all epsilon? (Sorry I don't know how to use symbols and stuffs on the computer). That is why I thought the sequence is constant. Why would you take epsilon less than 1?

Comment: @Kane What happens if we choose $\epsilon = 1/2$ ? Work out the details. And check out this link to learn how to write math here. It's really easy. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference