# Discrete Metric Spaces and Complete Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Consider the following conjecture of mine:

> If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ whose subspace topology is discrete, then $Y$ is closed in $X$.

If I'm not mistaken, $A = \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \Bbb{N}$ is a counterexample. Since $\{1\} = A \cap (\frac{3}{4},2)$ and $\{\frac{1}{n}\} = A \cap (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n-1})$ for all $n \ge 2$, all singletons in $A$ are open so $A$'s subspace topology is discrete. But $A$ is not closed in $\Bbb{R}$.

But this is rather confusing. [Since all discrete (metric) spaces are complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022355/prove-that-discrete-metric-space-is-complete), and since [a subspace of a complete metric space is closed iff it is complete](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subspace_of_Complete_Metric_Space_is_Closed_iff_Complete), shouldn't $A$ actually be closed? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrete metric refers to a particular metric on a space, that where $d(x,y) = 1$ for $x \neq y$. While the metric on your subspace generates the same discrete topology, it is not the same as the discrete metric and therefore doesn't need to be complete. **Completeness is only a property of the metric, not the topology.**

(If you look at the question you linked to, you'll notice that the key step is that if $d(x_n,x_m)< \frac{1}{2}$ then $x_n=x_m$. This is true for the discrete metric, but not true for your set.)

Comment: Hmm, but can't every discrete space be given the discrete metric and that metric will induce its topology? In other words, isn't a discrete space always metrizable?

Comment: You can certainly change the metric on your set to the discrete metric, yes, and that won't change the topology. But it is a meaningful change of the metric. There's no reason to expect that properties of the metric, like completeness, will be the same before and after you change the metric.

Comment: @Chesanator You say "Completeness is only a property of the metric, not the topology", but that second link seems to contradict what you are saying. That theorem gives a characterization of closed sets in a discrete space; and what it says is that any metric that induces that topology must make it a complete metric space. So the theorem does give a link between the metric and the topology.

Comment: That link is also in the context of a specific metric, the (complete) metric on the space that we are looking at subsets of. If we change that metric to one which induces the same topology but isn't complete, that theorem stops applying. Once again, we're looking at a property of a specific metric and not a property of the topology it induces.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up two concepts. The discrete metric is defined by $d(x,y)=1$ if $x \neq y$ and $0$ if $x=y$. With this metric any set becomes a complete metric space. Your set $A$ does not have discrete metric but its topology is discrete (in the sense every subset is open). Discrete metric and discrete topology are different concepts.